# I'm getting stuck with login page in cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.4

I'm getting stuck with login page in cakephp 2.4, can anyone help me figure it out what mistakes I have made. Thank you so much!
(why did I dont see the password in WHERE clause of the query??)

Here is sql file, the project file and two pictures describe the problem:

- SQL file: dropbox.com/s/b4pv419j09rp5jk/chickenrainshop.sql?dl=0
- Project file: dropbox.com/s/kextdrpzizyskwd/chickenrainshop.zip?dl=0

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are using default auth component to encode password, convert your password to database form and compare, or if you are using blowfish then compare with Security::hash($current_pass, 'blowfish', $pass_stored);

Comment: How did you add that user to database?

Comment: what is your problem anyway? please explain your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing the password column in the `WHERE` clause because Cakes authentication layer compares passwords at PHP level, using the configured password hasher, which by default is `SimplePasswordHasher` (at least in CakePHP 2.x), using `sha1`, `sha256`, or `md5`, depending on what's available on the system (in that order, and in any case salted with the `Security.salt` config value).

The password values in your database are most probably both wrong, the first one looks like `md5`, which is unlikely to be used by your app, and the second one is a plain string, which will never work.

So as already hinted in the comments, update your database with the correct password hashes. Ideally add the users to your database via your app.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Libraries > Components > Authentication > Hashing Passwords](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.10/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L122-L136**

Comment: It's work. How wonderful you guy are, I've got stuck for a week .. almost give up the project. Thank you so much @ndm